# Taking coins away randomly from 2 piles

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have 2 piles of coins, each with $n$ coins. Every time we randomly pick a pile and take away 1 coin. When one of the piles becomes empty, what is the expectation of the number of coins in the remaining pile?

Comment: let $f(n,m)$ be the answer when piles start off with $n,m$ coins. then $f(n,m) = \frac{1}{2}f(n-1,m)+\frac{1}{2}f(n,m-1)$. you also have the conditions $f(n,0) = n, f(0,m) = m$. solve the recurrence for $f(n,m)$ for general $n,m$. then see what you get for $n=m$

Comment: @mathworker21 - you mean there is a closed form for this?

Comment: @antkam i guess that's implicit in my comment. do u think there isn't? i didnt try

Comment: @mathworker21 - hmm...  will try tomorrow!  :)

Comment: Computation shows that  $$f(n,n)={(2n-1)!!\over(2n-2)!!}$$ for $n\leq20$, but I haven't tried to find the formula for $f(n,m)$ yet.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011354/banach-matchbox-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the number of potential draws from pile $i\in \{0,1\}$ until the other pile is empty. Then
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_i=k)=\binom{n+k-1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+k}.
$$
Letting $Y$ denote the number of remaining coins in a non-empty pile after the other pile has been emptied, for $m\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ one gets
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(Y=m)&=\mathsf{P}(Y=m,X_1<n)+\mathsf{P}(Y=m,X_2<n) \\
&=\mathsf{P}(X_1=n-m)+\mathsf{P}(X_2=n-m) \\
&=\binom{2n-m-1}{n-m}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-m-1}.
\end{align}
Finally,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}Y&=\sum_{m=1}^n m\binom{2n-m-1}{n-m}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-m-1}=\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}\frac{2n-1}{2^{2(n-1)}} \\
&=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n-2)!!}\approx\frac{2n-1}{\sqrt{\pi(n-1)}}\approx 2\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{\pi}}.
\end{align}

Comment: How do you get $\sum_{m=1}^n m\binom{2n-m-1}{n-m}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-m-1}=\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}\frac{2n-1}{2^{2(n-1)}}$?  I got this far, but couldn't see how to simplify the sum.

Comment: \begin{align}
&\sum_{m=1}^n m\binom{2n-m-1}{n-m}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-m-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)\binom{n+k-1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+k-1} \\
&\qquad =n-n\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+k} \\
&\qquad =n\binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}+n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-1}=\ldots,
\end{align}
where the second line uses the fact that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+k}=1.
$$

Comment: For the last identity see Example 2 in [this book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=QTfxn_gEbVYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=.+Egorychev.+Integral+Representation+and+the+Computation+of+Combinatorial+Sums&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK_9zFu-zkAhUN2KQKHZVxCTsQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=64&f=false).